# Why can't I run Solus OS?

Tags: boot, solus

I am trying to run **SolusOS** on my computer for a few days but after I choose it on my pendrive it just show a 5 sec countdown and then nothing happens, just a black screen with a cursor blinking.

I searched on internet and some people are having this trouble AFTER installation too, but in my case it doesn't even start the live system, I tried after pressing `Alt + F1`:

```
sudo systemctl stop lightdm
sudo systemctl start lightdm
sudo startx
```